# MS Access: Summing time greater than 24 hours in query restarts from 1 again

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a table trans_hist in MS Access program where time is stored in short Date format "HH:MM" ex:

[![Image][1]][1]

Now I have created a query which tells total time for each user (Just simply summing the time) but if the total time exceeds 24 hours then it resets and starts over again from 00:15(all time are stored in 15 minutes intervals)

**Problem: For Customer(UID) 1 the total time should have been 32:30 however it shows 8:30**

Current Result:

```
UID Time_Elapsed
1   5:00
1   8:30
1   9:00
1   6:00
2   2:15
2   2:00
3   1:15
5   4:00
1   4:00
```

Result:

[![Image][2]][2]

- DATA

Cust_UID    Trans_Date  Agen_Name   Prog_Name   Prime_Serv  Prime_Serv_Time
10014   13-Dec-15   LAC RA  BMC 01:00
10021   14-Dec-15   LAC RA  AP  01:00
10022   15-Dec-15   LAC RA  AP  01:00
10021   16-Dec-15   LAC RA  SM  00:45
10020   17-Dec-15   LAC RA  AP  01:00
10027   18-Dec-15   LAC RA  DA  00:15
10028   18-Dec-15   LAC RA  DA  00:15
10026   18-Dec-15   LAC RA  DA  00:15
10029   18-Dec-15   LAC RA  DA  00:15
10030   18-Dec-15   LAC RA  DA  00:15
10031   18-Dec-15   LAC RA  DA  00:15
10023   19-Dec-15   LAC RA  Clinical    02:00
10023   20-Dec-15   LAC RA  Clinical    01:30
10023   20-Dec-15   LAC RA  Clinical    02:00
10020   21-Dec-15   LAC RA  SM  00:15
10023   21-Dec-15   LAC RA  SM  00:30
10022   22-Dec-15   LAC RA  Clinical    00:30
10022   22-Dec-15   LAC RA  IB  00:30
10021   22-Dec-15   LAC RA  IB  00:30
10009   22-Dec-15   LAC RA  IB  00:30
10019   23-Dec-15   LAC RA  STM 00:45
10009   23-Dec-15   LAC RA  Staff - In  00:30
10021   23-Dec-15   LAC RA  Staff - In  00:30
10022   23-Dec-15   LAC RA  Staff - In  00:30
10024   23-Dec-15   LAC RA  Staff - In  00:30
10033   23-Dec-15   LAC RA  Staff - In  00:30
10025   23-Dec-15   LAC RA  Clinical    00:45
10035   28-Dec-15   LAC OA  CA  05:00
10040   28-Dec-15   LAC OA  CA  05:00
10039   28-Dec-15   LAC OA  CA  05:00
10038   28-Dec-15   LAC OA  CA  05:00
10042   28-Dec-15   LAC OA  CA  05:00
10036   28-Dec-15   LAC OA  CA  05:00
10037   28-Dec-15   LAC OA  CA  05:00
10006   30-Dec-15   LAC Test 1  DA  01:45
10005   30-Dec-15   LAC Test 2  DG  01:45
10015   30-Dec-15   LAC Test 2  IB  02:15
10015   30-Dec-15   LAC Test 4  DG  03:15
10019   30-Dec-15   LAC OA  CA  15:30
10005   31-Dec-15   LAC OA  CA  12:00

[Data][3]

Result

Prog_Name   Prime_Serv  Total_Serv_Time
OA  CA  62:30
RA  AP  3:0
RA  BMC 1:0
RA  Clinical    7:45
RA  DA  2:30
RA  IB  2:30
RA  Staff - In  2:30
RA  SM  2:30
RA  STM 1:45
Test 1  DA  2:45
Test 2  DG  2:45
Test 2  IB  2:15
Test 4  DG  3:15

[Result][4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope, this SQL query helps:

```
SELECT T.UID,
       CSTR(total_hours 
                + INT(total_min / 60)) 
                + ":" 
                + CSTR(total_min Mod 60) as result
FROM
    (SELECT UID,
            SUM(HOUR(TH.time_elapsed)) AS total_hours,
            SUM(MINUTE(TH.time_elapsed)) AS total_min
    FROM trans_hist AS TH
    GROUP BY UID) AS T
```

Comment: Hello @fabulaspb hope this query would work in MS Access.

Will update you once checked.

Comment: Worked :) Thanks alot!!!

Was just asking as I also know SQL but if you just explain to me how you broke and reattached them and what those CSTR and CINT do .

Comment: CSTR AND CINT are converting functions from one datatype to another (str, int). 
First step, I found total hours and minutes for each customer. 
Second step, total minutes could be more than 1 hour, so I had to add this hours to total hours.
Remainder of division was total minutes.

Comment: Hello found a problem in few cases where the total should be 1:45 or so it shows 2:45 one hour more than real please help.

Comment: SELECT T.Prog_Name, T.Prime_Serv, CStr([total_hours]+CInt([total_min]/60))+":"+CStr([total_min] Mod 60) AS Total_Serv_Time
FROM 
(SELECT TH.Prog_Name, TH.Prime_Serv, SUM(HOUR(TH.Prime_Serv_Time)) AS total_hours, SUM(MINUTE(TH.Prime_Serv_Time)) AS total_min 
 FROM Time_Trans_Hist AS TH 
 WHERE (((Trans_Date) Between [Start_Date] And [End_Date])) 
 GROUP BY Prog_Name, Prime_Serv)  AS T;

Above is the real query which I am running hope would clarify more.

Comment: I'll check it. What test case did you use?

Comment: I modified my query, replaced CINT to INT function. CINT works as round function, in my case I have to use floor function (int(value))

Comment: That Worked Thanks :)

Comment: Hello @fabulaspb need your help again .. please help out! I am trying to put a criteria in sql query where I already have a loots of criteria working but it's not including null values in delivery date field.
(If you would like will send you the whole query) problem below:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169216/iifformcontrolname-1-is-null-in-access-query-criteria

Answer (score 2):

Use a function like this:

```
Public Function FormatHourMinute( _
  ByVal datTime As Date, _
  Optional ByVal strSeparator As String = ":") _
  As String

' Returns count of days, hours and minutes of datTime
' converted to hours and minutes as a formatted string
' with an optional choice of time separator.
'
' Example:
'   datTime: #10:03# + #20:01#
'   returns: 30:04
'
' 2005-02-05. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim strHour       As String
  Dim strMinute     As String
  Dim strHourMinute As String

  strHour = CStr(Fix(datTime) * 24 + Hour(datTime))
  ' Add leading zero to minute count when needed.
  strMinute = Right("0" & CStr(Minute(datTime)), 2)
  strHourMinute = strHour & strSeparator & strMinute

  FormatHourMinute = strHourMinute

End Function
```

and a simple query:

```
Select 
    UID,
    FormatHourMinute(Sum([Time_Elapsed])) As TotalTime
From
    trans_hist 
Group By
    UID
```

Comment: Hello Gustav, Thanks first of all. I know how to use VB but here I am not sure where to put that VB script.

I am bit beginner so your help  required here.

Thanks

Comment: Create a new module. Copy and paste the function. Compile and save the module.

Comment: Hello Gustav ,

Please help me getting out of this great problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961585/attaching-access-form-and-subform-data-in-mail-body

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT UID, switch (
t>1 , '00:15' 
,true,format(t,'hh:mm')
) as Time_Elapsed from
(
SELECT UID, sum(Time_Elapsed) as t
From Table1
Group By UID
)
```