# Attaching access form and subform data in mail body

Tags: email, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, outlook-2010

Thanks in advance :), I am trying to attach the data of subform also in mail body.

Current Status: I am able to attach Main forms data and generate mail but unable to attach subform's data as it only includes the first row, Tryied doing it through Subform and query both but no success. I will prefer to do it by subform itself. Subform's Name is : "subUpdateOrder". VB Code:

```
Private Sub InformCustomer_Click()

On Error GoTo Err_InformCustomer_Click

    Dim CustName As String      ' Customer Name
    Dim varTo As Variant        '-- Address for SendObject
    Dim stText As String        '-- E-mail text
    Dim DelDate As Variant      '-- Rec date for e-mail text
    Dim stSubject As String     '-- Subject line of e-mail
    Dim stOrderID As String     '-- The Order ID from form
    Dim detailQry As String
    'Dim stHelpDesk As String    '-- Person who assigned ticket
    'Dim strSQL As String        '-- Create SQL update statement
    'Dim errLoop As Error

    CstName = Me![CustName]
    varTo = Me![CustEmail]
    stSubject = ":: Update - Oder Status ::"
    stOrderID = Me.[OdrID]
    DelDate = Me.[OdrDeliveryDate]
    stText = "Dear" & CstName & _
             "You have been assigned a new ticket." & Chr$(13) & Chr$(13) & _
             "Order Number: " & stOrderID & Chr$(13) & _
             "Please refer to your order status " & Chr$(13) & _
             "Exp Delevery Date: " & DelDate & Chr$(13) & Chr$(13) & _
              dQuery & Chr$(13) & _
             "This is an automated message. Please do not respond to this e-mail."

    'Write the e-mail content for sending to assignee
    DoCmd.SendObject , , acFormatTXT, varTo, , , stSubject, stText, True
  Err_InformCustomer_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Form Img: [Form and Command1 button to run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EoPe.png)

Comment: Hello Andre, 

Code is written in same formatting and it's generating the email as well with all variables on Parent Form but it's not populating the subform's or query's data .. 
Problem where my code says  " dQuery & Chr$(13) & _ "  , I am not sure how to refer the same whether for query or subform it seems that I have to loop and print all row's data in email body . Please refer below the mailcontent which gets generated when this code gets fired (varriables bound are highlighted):

**************************

Please help

Comment: Continued...
(variables are bold and OdrUpdatetoCustomer is the query supposed to populate the mailbody also):

Dear **Test 1**
You have been assigned a new ticket.

Order Number: **1**
Please refer to your order status 
Exp Delevery Date: **17-01-2016**

**OdrUpdatetoCustomer**
This is an automated message. Please do not respond to this e-mail.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like (to insert before `CstName = Me![CustName]`):

```
Dim dQuery As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = Me!NameOfYourSubformCONTROL.Form.RecordsetClone
While Not rs.EOF
     dQuery = dQuery & rs![Brand Name].Value & vbTab & rs![Model Name].Value & vbTab & rs![Color].Value & vbCrLF 
Wend
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Please help in appending it in that whole bunch of code please.

Would be really greatful

Comment: No big deal. As I wrote, just _insert before CstName = Me![CustName]_ in your existing code.